# Module not excluded on Wildfly

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

We want to exclude the `modules\system\layers\base\javax\servlet\jstl\api\main\jboss-jstl-api_1.2_spec-1.1.2.Final.jar` from our web application deployment (WAR file).

Hence we have the following configuration in `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\jboss-deployment-structure.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javax.servlet.jstl.api"/>
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="deployment.my-dependencies.jar"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

In the Wildfly log I see that `my-dependencies.jar` is added as a `ModuleDependency`. But when searching for `javax.servlet.jstl.api` I only see this:

> 2015-04-03 15:22:11,971 DEBUG [org.jboss.modules] (ServerService
>   Thread Pool -- 12) Module javax.servlet.jstl.api:main defined by local
>   module loader @1f7c9157 (finder: local module finder @2b29f6e7 (roots:
>   C:\Users\me\Documents\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\modules,C:\Users\me\Documents\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))

Why isn't the module excluded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: It seems that modules that are part of a user dependency can not be excluded.

---

It seems like the mechanism doesn't work as described in the [Wildfly documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly). I was not able to exclude that module.

Answer (score 1):

Yep. I was trying to upgrade to Spring Framework to v4.3. It has upped some minimum dependency requirements. One such example is Jackson min version required is 2.6+

Wildfly loads jackson that comes packaged (v2.4.1 in Wildfly 8.2.1), and it won't be excluded using jboss-deployment-structure.xml.
I was trying to see if the upgrade did not involve making changes to the installed server which takes this upgrade out of source control.

Comment: you also need to exclude other modules that depend on jackson2 (such as org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider) See:[Wildfly 9  How do I exclude Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37060294)