# Wildfly 9 - How do I exclude Jackson

Tags: jackson, wildfly-9

I'm running into a Jackson serialization issue with null values in maps.  Apparently this is a known bug in the Jackson version used by Wildfly 9 (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-4906).  I'd like to use the current version of Jackson; however, I'm having trouble excluding the version used by Wildfly.  I tried excluding the module in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` but the exclusion is not working.

[image: jboss-deployment-structure.xml]

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: May I know where you found the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I just ran into this issue myself.

After upgrading a library in my application, I received the following error on a request:

```
Exception handling request to /path: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.hasToken(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonToken;)
```

**Here is how I solved it:**

I obviously had to exclude `jackson-core-2.5.1` that wildfly-9 provides.

I listed all modules that depend on 'jackson-core' with `/opt/wildfly/modules# grep -R 'jackson-core'`

Then I created a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` in my `WEB-INF` folder:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I solved it the same way and forgot to update the ticket.

Comment: You solve my entire life. Seriously. You solved it. Thanks!

Comment: It works with Wildfly 10.1.0 Final version - and it save my faith.

Comment: It works with JBoss EAP 7.1.6 - and you saved my day. Now I will always use grep -R '<offending-lib>' in the modules folder, if I run into similar issues. (had some in the past...)

Comment: Do I need to configure somewhere for my jboss or my server to point to this `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` ? I try to create a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` in my WebContent/WEB-INF/ and put in the same content, restart my server, still no effect.

Comment: @PanadolChong I did no such thing.

Comment: This isn't working for wildfly 21, OpenJDK 11 and Spring boot 2.7 web deployment, jackson jars coming with Springboot. what did i miss?

Answer (score 10):

I had similar issue. I had to exclude whole jax-rs subsytem

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
<deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
    ...
</deployment>
```

after that I was able to use my version of Jackson.

Comment: This extra step was absolutely necessary. The accepted solution did not work on its own without this.