# Wildfly 10 - Deploy an application with newer version of jackson

Tags: jackson, wildfly, wildfly-10

I have an application (build with maven, packaged as war-file)
that requires jackson-core version 2.6.6.
Wildfly 10 already has jackson but in version 2.5.4.

What can i do to successfully deploy my application?

Comment: Could jboss-deployment-structure with exclusions be a way? What should i exclude here?

Answer (score 0):

Using jboss-deployment-structure [as you mentioned in your comment] to exclude jaxrs could work [assuming you don't need RESTEasy, and are using something like Spring WebMVC instead].  An example of doing so can be seen here:

[Wildfly 9 - How do I exclude Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37060294/wildfly-9-how-do-i-exclude-jackson)

Alternatively, you could disable jaxrs in your WildFly config by removing

```
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
```

and

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
```

from your $WILDFLY_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml [or whatever configuration you're using].