# Unable to exclude Jackson jars in WildFly

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

My application uses Jackson libraries of version 2.8.2 and I added them `WEB-INF/LIB` directory in my WAR file. As my WildFly (10.0.0.Final) also contains Jackson libraries (old versions) I have decided not to load them by excluding them in the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file as shown below:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="resteasy" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy" />
            <module name="org.apache.httpcomponents" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations" />
             <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
        <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

But my application is not getting deployed and WildFly throws the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig.withDefaultPrettyPrinter(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/PrettyPrinter;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationConfig;
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.<init>(XmlMapper.java:86)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.<init>(XmlMapper.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.<init>(XmlMapper.java:63)
```

It seems the WildFly is not excluding the Jackson libraries correctly. Please help.

Comment: If you use maven you could give them a "provided" scope (and not put them in webinf/lib.

Comment: @assylias But I need the Jackson jars of version(2.8.2) which are not provided by Wildfly 10.0.0.Final and I can't upgrade Wildfly.

Comment: Excluded subsystem's name must be [jaxrs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37060294/wildfly-9-how-do-i-exclude-jackson)

Comment: @CWasp Great! That worked. I excluded the JPA but forgot to exclude the jaxrs. Thanks for reminding me.