# How to exclude the specific jar from global module in jboss?

Tags: jboss, war, deployment-descriptor

I have a war file that contains, some jackson dependencies and then when I try to deploy it on **jboss eap 7.3** server, war deployment fails

Due to, as different version of these **jackson** jar are included via global modules. That I cannot or remove from their.

So I create a **jboss-deployment-structure.xm**l file and tried excluding specific jar's inside the global module's but it did not worked.

But I was **successful in excluding the whole global modules that I don't want**.

This is what I tried!!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
      <module name="fb_library" />
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

This above **config works, but it excludes the whole global fb_library folder**, But as I **needed to exclude some specific jar** so tried this and it gave error as wrong format for jboss-deployment-structure.xml

**This gave error of wrong config** as mentioned above

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
      <resources>  
        <resource-root path="jackson-core-2.6.6.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jackson-annotations-2.6.0.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.6.6.jar"/>  
      </resources> 
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

PS:- I have updated the question, as suggested by some members in chat, previously I was asking the wrong question. Apologies for that.

Again I tried this and not working

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <deployment>
<exclusions>
<module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core" />
<module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation" />
<module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module" />
<module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs" />
<module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json" />
<module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb" />
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: This is a jboss question, not a Maven question. You should tag it that way.

Comment: You need to include a jboss deployment descriptor indicating you want to prefer jars from your war over those from the server. I.e. parent-last classloading or whatever that is called nowadays. Trying to solve this with maven won't work.

Comment: @M.Deinum but if I do that in jboss deployment descriptor, then it will done for every war that is deployed on jboss. I want to this this only for my specific war file. As on our jboss more than 20 apps are deployed.

Comment: No it won't as the descriptor is part of this war.

Comment: @M.Deinum ok let me look into it

Comment: @M.Deinum but I have a springboot project that doesn't contain the web.xml file. And if I somehow add the web.xml then can you guide me as what kind of configuration do I need to add in that file to set the priority higher

Comment: I nowhere mentioned the web.xml... I mentioned the jboss specific deployment descriptor, which contains all sorts of stuff like classloading preference, which modules to use from where, which to exclude etc. etc.

Comment: @M.Deinum I searched online for deployment descriptor it gave result as web.xml. Please can you share a link or something. It would be very helpfull.

Comment: You are using JBoss, read the jboss documentation which shows the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`. Assuming that you are using a recent version of JBoss or WildFly.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried creating jboss-deployment-descriptor.xml and added it to web-inf folder, but still results in same error.
Adding content of jboss descriptor in next cmt.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
  <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
  <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
  <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
  <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>

Comment: Please don’t add additional information as comments, as those are totally unreadable. Instead edit your question and add it with proper formatting.

Comment: @M.Deinum Done that please check.

Answer (score 1):

In jboss-deployment-structure, you are not allowed to add resources content (Jar files).
you need to specify the module name added by the dependency jar file itself here is an example :
here is a jackson jar that I want to exclude from jboss modules :
[image: JAckson module]

the module name is : com.fasterxml.jackson.core
and in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml it will be :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
      <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core" />
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: I have one question, Actually I have mentioned my jackson jar are added by another team in custom fb_library, and it is loading from their. And they have added fb_library in standalone.xml as global module. So Will this solution work in that case too???

Comment: Yes, coz jboss-deployment-structure  control class loading so  it doesn't matter from where the module was inected it will be excluded in the class loading process. __document_: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class%20Loading%20in%20AS7.html#:~:text=JBoss%20Deployment%20Structure%20File,%2DINF%20for%20web%20deployments).

Comment: Not working in my case, even after excluding by package name. And Please see my jboss-deployment-structure.xml file

Comment: Still facing this error:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module"}

Comment: can you please have a look as it is not working

Comment: obviously, it's a classCastException.
does this issue appears when you did exclude your target modules?
please share the server logs and the scenario done

Comment: Yes this issue appeared after the exclusion also. In the question I have updated the jboss-deployment-structure.xml that I wrote and it did not worked. And basically ClassCastException: is there, currently I am unable to connect to server will share logs after a while. Can you guess or make an assumption as why my jboss-deployment-structure.xml is not working

Comment: Actually your jboss-deployment-structure.xml is working fine ( the exclusion process done successfully). 
There is something wrong with your application itself,I think one of the excluded modules is needed in your classpath.

Comment: Does excluding it from jboss-deployment-structure.xml, also excludes it from loading altogether, As I have to load the latest version of jackson that I add in POM file, but what was happening is JBOSS container had already Jackson but its version was quite old, I just need to override that version.

Comment: Exclusion in the modules section is done with the module structure name so any module that matches the specified name will be excluded (for any version).

Answer (score 0):

This answer solve my problems for com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor
FYI
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37859612/14337508